# wicket - adding tabs dynamicly without rendering all tabs

Tags: java, wicket

I would like to create tab panel where the tabs are created dynamically in wicket 
and by doing it in a list of tabs where every time I create tab , I want only this tab to be rendered , and not creating all the view from start via ajax

is there another framework that would do it ?

Comment: Thats the default behavior as far as I remeber? Have you checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [TabbedPanel](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/extensions/markup/html/tabs/TabbedPanel.html) or the [AjaxTabbedPanel](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/extensions/ajax/markup/html/tabs/AjaxTabbedPanel.html) from the wicket-extensions for this. Both require a List for the tabs to display. You can keep a reference to this list and add new entries.

Both implementations only create the Component for the tab content when the tab is created.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use client-side only tabs like JQuery UI Tabs: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation and then render the content of the Tabs as Panels and not as Wicket TabbedPanel tabs.